# tikz matrix alignment problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a explanation of SAD (Sum of Absolute differences).
After a lot of tweaking I have something that sort of looks OK except that the horizontal as well as the vertical alignment/distances are terrible!
And, as you can see, everything is hardcoded.

How can I get everything to line up beautifully?

Label Right which isn't aligned with `Left` and `Center` as well as the vertical distance between the 3 "rows". The `Left, Center & Right` matrixes should probably be moved to the right a bit to have everything centered on some imaginary vertical axis. To add a offset repetable until it looks better is a pain since there are many values to change, e.g. for the grids.

Output:

[image: sad]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=640x480,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max size={.95\textwidth}{.8\textheight}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (-.75,-.75) grid (.75,.75);
        \matrix (template) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
        2 & 5 & 5 \\
        4 & 0 & 7 \\
        7 & 5 & 9 \\
        };
        \node[label={[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]Template}] at (template.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (1.75,-.75) grid (4.25,.75);
        \matrix (search) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (3,0){
        2 & 7 & \node[red]{5}; & \node[red]{8}; & \node[red]{6}; \\
        1 & 7 & \node[red]{4}; & \node[red]{2}; & \node[red]{7}; \\
        8 & 4 & \node[red]{6}; & \node[red]{8}; & \node[red]{5}; \\
        };
        \node[label={Search Image}] at (search.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (-1.75,-3.75) grid (-.25,-2.25);
        \matrix (left) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (-1,-3){
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        3 & 7 & 3 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        };
        \node[label={Left}] at (left.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (.25,-3.75) grid (1.75,-2.25);
        \matrix (center) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (1,-3){
        5 & 0 & 3 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 \\
        3 & 1 & 1 \\
        };
        \node[label={Center}] at (center.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (2.25,-3.75) grid (3.75,-2.25);
        \matrix (right) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (3,-3){
        \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{1}; \\
        \node[red]{0}; & \node[red]{2}; & \node[red]{0}; \\
        \node[red]{1}; & \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{4}; \\
        };
        \node[label={Right}] at (right.north) {};

        \matrix (sad) [matrix of nodes] at (1,-5) {
        20 & 25 & \node[red]{17}; \\
        };
        \node[label={SAD}] at (sad.north) {};
        % ..
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly what you mean by "line up beautifully". Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: sorry, updated MWE. I mainly thought about the label `Right` which isn't aligned with `Left` and `Center` as well as the vertical distance between the 3 "rows"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very different version, where no positions are explicit. The `center` matrix is defined first, and the other placed relative to this. This gives a consistent distance between (the edges) of the matrices. You can modify the spacing by changing the `node distance` key that I added to the `tikzpicture` options. The first value is the vertical spacing, the second is the horizontal. The `positioning` library is added to allow this type of positioning.

The vertical alignment of `Right` is fixed by adding a `text depth` to each of the label nodes (similar to [Comma alignment problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160569/use-comma-alignement-problem/)).

To add options to a node in a `matrix of nodes` you can add `|[<options>]|` to the beginning of the cell. I used this to make the some values `|[red]|`. (In hindsight: For the `right` matrix you could just add `red` to the matrix options instead. For `search` you could also modify the `column 3`/`column 4`/`column 5` styles, instead of modifying each cell in those columns.)

I also added a couple of styles, to reduce code repetition.

The grids are drawn after the matrices, but on the background layer with the help of the `backgrounds` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=640x480,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix, positioning,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 0.5cm,
  matrixlabel/.style={text depth=3pt,above},
  matrixnodes/.style={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]

\matrix (center) 
   [matrix of nodes,
    nodes={matrixnodes}]{
        5 & 0 & 3 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 \\
        3 & 1 & 1 \\
        };
\node [matrixlabel] at (center.north) {Center};

\matrix (right)
    [matrix of nodes,
     nodes={matrixnodes},
     right=of center]  {
        |[red]| {3} & |[red]| 3 & |[red]| 1 \\
        |[red]| 0 & |[red]| 2 & |[red]| 0 \\
        |[red]| 1 & |[red]| 3 & |[red]| 4 \\
        };
\node [matrixlabel] at (right.north) {Right};

\matrix (left)
    [matrix of nodes,
     nodes={matrixnodes},
     left=of center] {
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        3 & 7 & 3 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        };
\node [matrixlabel] at (left.north) {Left};

\matrix (template)
    [matrix of nodes,
    nodes={matrixnodes},
    above=of left.north west,
    anchor=south west] {
        2 & 5 & 5 \\
        4 & 0 & 7 \\
        7 & 5 & 9 \\
        };
\node[matrixlabel] at (template.north) {Template};

\matrix (search) 
    [matrix of nodes,
     nodes={matrixnodes},
     above=of right.north east,
     anchor=south east] {
        2 & 7 & |[red]| 5 & |[red]| 8 & |[red]| 6 \\
        1 & 7 & |[red]| 4 & |[red]| 2 & |[red]| 7 \\
        8 & 4 & |[red]| 6 & |[red]| 8 & |[red]| 5 \\
        };
\node[matrixlabel] at (search.north) {Search Image};


\matrix (sad) 
     [matrix of nodes,
     below=of center]  {
        20 & 25 & |[red]| 17 \\
        };
\node[matrixlabel] at (sad.north) {SAD};

\begin{scope}[on background layer,lightgray]
  \foreach \mat in {template, left, center, right} {
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
      \draw  (\mat-\i-1.west) -- (\mat-\i-3.east);
      \draw  (\mat-1-\i.north) -- (\mat-3-\i.south);
     }
   }

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
   \draw  (search-1-\i.north) -- (search-3-\i.south);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
   \draw  (search-\i-1.west) -- (search-\i-5.east);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the lesson, I learnt a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `scope` environment and with `xshift` parameter:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=640x480,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max size={.95\textwidth}{.8\textheight}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (-.75,-.75) grid (.75,.75);
        \matrix (template) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}]{
        2 & 5 & 5 \\
        4 & 0 & 7 \\
        7 & 5 & 9 \\
        };
        \node[label={[xshift=0cm, yshift=0cm]Template}] at (template.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (1.75,-.75) grid (4.25,.75);
        \matrix (search) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (3,0){
        2 & 7 & \node[red]{5}; & \node[red]{8}; & \node[red]{6}; \\
        1 & 7 & \node[red]{4}; & \node[red]{2}; & \node[red]{7}; \\
        8 & 4 & \node[red]{6}; & \node[red]{8}; & \node[red]{5}; \\
        };
        \node[label={Search Image}] at (search.north) {};

 \begin{scope}[xshift=0.75cm]
        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (-1.75,-3.75) grid (-.25,-2.25);
        \matrix (left) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (-1,-3){
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        3 & 7 & 3 \\
        1 & 1 & 3 \\
        };

        \node[label={Left}] at (left.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (.25,-3.75) grid (1.75,-2.25);
        \matrix (center) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (1,-3){
        5 & 0 & 3 \\
        3 & 4 & 5 \\
        3 & 1 & 1 \\
        };
        \node[label={Center}] at (center.north) {};

        \draw[step=0.5cm,color=lightgray] (2.25,-3.75) grid (3.75,-2.25);
        \matrix (right) [matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=center,minimum height=.5cm}] at (3,-3){
        \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{1}; \\
        \node[red]{0}; & \node[red]{2}; & \node[red]{0}; \\
        \node[red]{1}; & \node[red]{3}; & \node[red]{4}; \\
        };
        \node[label={Right}] at (right.north) {};

        \matrix (sad) [matrix of nodes] at (1,-5) {
        20 & 25 & \node[red]{17}; \\
        };
 \end{scope}
        \node[label={SAD}] at (sad.north) {};

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your "Right" label is still vertically higher than the "Left" and "Center" labels.