# tikz node dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

How can I get `tikz` node dimensions such as height and width? I am interested to use these parameters to precisely calculate placement of objects, e.g. using `<a.height>` in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a) {
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    };
    \node(b) at (0, <a.height>*3/4){label};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58283/tikz-how-to-determine-the-vector-between-two-co-ordinates/58287#58287

Comment: Something like `\node(b) at (a.south!1.25!a.north)` might work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two examples where the desired result is obtained without knowing node dimensions. The second one uses `calc` tikzlibrary

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(a) {
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    };
    \path (a.center)--(a.north) node[pos=.75, right] {label without calc};
    \node[left] at ($(a.center)!.75!(a.north)$) {label with calc};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

Let's suppose we want the label `label without calc` 2cm to the right and 1cm up  from its actual position in previous example: `\path (a.center)--(a.north) node[pos=.75, right] {label without calc}`. We can use `positioning` library to move the node relative to the corresponding point on path. In this case we can say `above right=1cm and 2cm` but this will use `south west` anchor for placement and we want `west`, then we add `anchor=west` after `above right` option:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (a) {
      \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    };
    \path (a.center)--(a.north) node[draw, pos=.75, above right=1cm and 2cm, anchor=west, red] (b) {label without calc};
    \node[left] (c) at ($(a.center)!.75!(a.north)$) {label with calc};

    %Some auxiliary elements.
    \draw[red,<->] (a.center)--(c.east) node[midway, right] {75\%};
    \draw[red,<->] (c.east)--(a.north) node[midway,right] {25\%};
    \fill[red] (c.east) circle (1pt);
    \draw[red,<->] (c.east)-|(b.west)  node[pos=0.25,below] {2 cm} node[pos=0.75,left] {1 cm};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I still nudge e.g. + (2, 1) inside the expression  \path (a.center)--(a.north) node[pos=.75, right]

Comment: @Viesturs Where in `\path (a.center)--(a.north) node[pos=.75, right]` do you want to use `+(2,1)`? In any case, you can use `positioning` library an say `node[above right=2cm and 1cm of ...]`

Comment: I want to nudge the result given by  `(a.center)--(a.north) node[pos=.75`, by + (2, 1). I don't know the correct syntax for that.

Comment: @Viesturs Does the updated answer solve your question?

Comment: Yes, this is what I imagined.